# InDesign inline text wrap object

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, paragraph-styles, object-styles

Here's my current InDesign problem. I'm given text that, when imported, looks like this, with embedded links in the paragraph:

[image]

The final product has to look like this, with proper spacing around the images:

[image]

My current solution is to select the affected lines of text and change their leading amount:

[image]

However, I'd like a more automated and responsive solution that would simply add padding around the top and bottom of the inline objects. Text Wrap seems to work for the bottom of the object, but never the top. Hopefully someone knows an awesome workaround here. It would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three things you must do:

1. Set the whole text leading to **Automatic**
2. Change the Anchor Object **Y Offset** to a negative number

[image: Y Offset]

3. Set the Anchor Object **Text Wrap** to **Jump Object**

[image: Text Wrap]

---

[image: adding text]

Comment: Thank you! This will require a re-thinking of our body paragraph styles, but it's a fantastic trick.